# Compute the mean and std of a random variable from its correlation with known random variables?

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

**Context**

I'm running statistical simulations on IQ distribution among people and I would like to sample the IQ of a child given :

1. The general distribution of IQ following : 
   $$ \mathcal{N}(100, 15.5) \text{ for male}$$
   $$ \mathcal{N}(100, 14.5) \text{ for female}$$
2. The correlation between the average of parents' IQ and their child IQ (0.5).
3. Both parents' IQs
4. The sex of the child

**Question**

Is it possible to do that and if it is, how ?

Comment: Do you know the average of the parents' IQ, and the sex of the child?

Comment: Yes I know that !

Comment: I edited the question since it was not clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be random variables corresponding to the IQ of the mother and father. The average of their IQs also has a normal distribution with

$$
Y_1 \equiv \frac{X_1 + X_2}{2} \sim \mathcal{N}(100, \frac{1}{4}(15.5 + 14.5 + 2\mathrm{Cov}(X_1, X_2)).
$$

It's probably the case that $\mathrm{Cov}(X_1, X_2) \neq 0$ for parents of the child - you could include this in your simulations if you wished. Anyway, continue by letting $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{4}(15.5 + 14.5 + 2\mathrm{Cov}(X_1, X_2))$.

Now if $Y_2$ is another random variable for the IQ of the child (say it's a girl) then the joint distribution of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ is multivariate normal with

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    Y_1 \\
    Y_2 \\
\end{pmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
    100 \\
    100 \\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
    \sigma^2 & \mathrm{Cov}(Y_1, Y_2) \\
    \mathrm{Cov}(Y_1, Y_2) & 14.5\\
\end{pmatrix} \right).
$$

The off-diagonal covariance terms can be found by the definition of correlation

$$
\frac{\mathrm{Cov}(Y_1, Y_2)}{\sqrt{14.5}\sqrt{\sigma^2}} = 0.5.
$$

Now you can use the formula for the [conditional distribution of the multivariate normal](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Multivariate_normal_distribution#/Conditional_distributions) to find the distribution of $Y_2 | Y_1 = y_1$ where $y_1$ is the realisation of the parent's average IQ, which you have. This should give you a univariate distribution which can be simulated from easily (say using `rnorm` if you are using R.)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: How does this answer the question as phrased? The question says the parents' IQs are given; their constant, not random variables. The random variable was the IQ of the child.

Comment: I interpreted the parent's IQs to be given as realisations from the general distribution of IQ. If it were instead a constant, how would one interpret $\rho = 0.5$? The correlation would be undefined I think